# Issue in binding object with categoryfield of Angular kendo chart

Tags: kendo-ui, angular7, kendo-chart

For kendo chart, when I bind object value with 'categoryField' , chart is not rendered properly

Here I have demonstrated this with bar chart:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oykufy